# Terraform : How to ignore the Optional block if the Property - list of string is Empty

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm just starting with the terraform, The below is my terraform code. From the below [Cors](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/signalr_service) is an Optional block, where it has the property of allowed origins which is list of strings(URL or *)

```
resource "azurerm_signalr_service" "signalr_service" {
  
  name="${var.signalr_name}"
  location = "${var.resource_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"

  sku {
    name     = "${var.sku_name}"
    capacity = "${var.sku_capacity}"
  }
        
#Cors is an optional block
  cors {
    allowed_origins = "${var.cors_allowed_origins}"
  }
```

Varilabe.tf:

```
variable "allowed_origins" {
  type = "list"
  description = "A list of origins which should be able to make cross-origin calls. * can be used to allow all calls"
  default = []
}
```

Users may/maynot provide the `allowed_origns` , if they provide there is no problem, but if they don't provide

1. Default as an empty list[]: when I pass the empty list the `allowed_origns`  it fails saying that not a valid URL
2. Default as an `null`: If I pass as null, `allowed_origin` alone gets null and cors is passing as an empty block i.e,`cors{}` which also fails due to property missing error

Now my question is how to make the entire cors block to ignore if the user doesn't provide any values to the `allowed_origins` and what would be the default I should use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to make CORS block optional:

```
resource "azurerm_signalr_service" "signalr_service" {
  
  name="${var.signalr_name}"
  location = "${var.resource_location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"

  sku {
    name     = "${var.sku_name}"
    capacity = "${var.sku_capacity}"
  }
        
  dynamic "cors" {
    for_each = length(var.cors_allowed_origins) > 0 ? [1] : []
    content {
        allowed_origins = "${var.cors_allowed_origins}"
    }
  }
}
```

Default value of `[]` is fine.